# Typescript decorator circular dependency

Tags: typescript

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jackson-js-poly-cycle-import-6x6yo)

The typescript polymorphic type handing with [`jackson-js`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/jackson-js/) comes from
https://dev.to/pichillilorenzo/jackson-js-powerful-javascript-decorators-to-serialize-deserialize-objects-into-json-and-vice-versa-part-1-5484

Class `Dog` extends class `Animal`, and a decorator `@JsonSubTypes` on class `Animal` uses `Dog`.

If I put class `Animal` and `Dog` in the same file, it works as expected, `animal.say()` prints `Wang!` to console.

```js
// src/samefile/Animal.ts
import {
  JsonClassType,
  JsonProperty,
  JsonTypeInfo,
  JsonTypeInfoId,
  JsonTypeInfoAs,
  JsonSubTypes,
  JsonTypeName
} from "jackson-js";

@JsonTypeInfo({
  use: JsonTypeInfoId.NAME,
  include: JsonTypeInfoAs.PROPERTY,
  property: "type"
})
@JsonSubTypes({
  types: [{ class: () => Dog, name: "dog" }]
})
export class Animal {
  @JsonProperty()
  @JsonClassType({ type: () => [String] })
  name: string;

  @JsonProperty()
  @JsonClassType({ type: () => [String] })
  type: string;

  constructor(type: string, name: string) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
  }

  say() {
    console.log("Ah!");
  }
}

@JsonTypeName({ value: "dog" })
export class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super("dog", name);
  }

  say() {
    console.log("Wang!");
  }
}
```

```js
// src/samefile/test.ts
import { ObjectMapper } from "jackson-js";
import { Animal } from "./Animal";
import { Dog } from "./Animal";
// import { Dog } from "./Dog";

const dog = new Dog("Super");
const objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
const jsonString = objectMapper.stringify<Animal>(dog);
console.log(jsonString); // {"name":"Super","type":"dog"}

const animal = objectMapper.parse<Animal>(jsonString, {
  mainCreator: () => [Animal]
});
animal.say(); // Wang!
```

If I move the Dog code to a separate file `Dog.ts`, when I call `objectMapper.parse`, I got error `Super expression must either be null or a function`. See folder `src/difffile`

`import type { Dog } from "./Dog"` doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import order from

```
import { Animal } from "./Animal";
import { Dog } from "./Dog";
```

to

```
import { Dog } from "./Dog";
import { Animal } from "./Animal";
```

fixes

Comment: [This artical](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) is useful.